# Reorganizing large dataset for transition matrix (R studio)

Tags: r

I need to make a transition matrix (Markov). In order to do so I need to reorganize my data so that each column is a participant and each row a behavior.
Currently my data is organized as such:

```
participant<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
eventorder<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
behavior<-c("fumble","neutral","look_down","head_side","Talking","Look_at",
           "Neutral","Talking","Fumble","Look_away","Talking","Fumble",
           "Nod","Look_at","Eyebrow_lift")
dat<-data.frame(participant,eventorder,behavior)
```

I would like my dataset to look like this:

```
participant1<-c("fumble","neutral","look_down","head_side","Talking")
participant2<-c("Look_at", "Neutral","Talking","Fumble","Look_away")
participant3<-c("Talking","Fumble", "Nod","Look_at","Eyebrow_lift")

dat2<-data.frame(participant1,participant2,participant3)
```

Is anyone aware of a way to do this in R Studio? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` package. `pivot_wider(dat,names_from = participant, values_from = behavior, id_cols = eventorder, names_glue = "participant_{participant}")`

Answer (score 0):

Using `pivot_wider()` from the package `{dplyr}`:

```
dat3 <- tidyr::pivot_wider(dat,
                           names_from = "participant",
                           names_prefix = "participant",
                           values_from = "behavior")

all.equal(dat2, dat3 |> dplyr::select(-eventorder) |> as.data.frame())
#> TRUE
```

As you can notice, it keeps the "eventorder" column and returns a tibble instead of a dataframe, so I have to change that before comparing to `dat2` in `all.equal()`.